# Dividing a dataset into three subsets with similar development of mean

Tags: python, r, dataset, subset, similarity

I have a simple set of data that shows a certain score over time for each data point. This dataset looks somewhat like this:

| id | day 1 | day 2 | day 3 | day 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.5 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 2.25 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 | 2.75 |
| 3 | 0 | 0.5 | 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**The objective is to divide this dataset into 3 groups which have a similar mean-value for any given day**. I know that this is an NP-minimization problem and finding the optimal solution is inefficient. But an approximate solution would be absolutely fine.

Randomly picking data points and putting them into one of the groups showed these results:
[image]

Where global-mean is the mean of the unsplit data, group1-3 are the split groups.
Which already does not look too bad, however there is obviously room for improvement, as this was just randomly thrown together.

The longer I thought about this problem, the more complex it seemed to grow.

I am currently using Python 3.10 to try and solve it.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this? It does not necessarily have to be an elegant solution. Brute force should yield adequate results too, right?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you looking for a full algorithm implemented? Try to take a look at K-Mean clustering and come back with a minimal reproducible code so we can help you if there are any problems :)

Comment: Depending on your needs and how many IDs there are the simple randomisation might be pretty close to what you want.  You could improve that with a 'minimisation' approach whereby you choose a group at random for ID 1 and then add each subsequent ID to the group chosen such that the difference between the groups is minimised (by some criterion).